# Report not rendering using SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

**SSRS 2005** : I am writing RDL file in code itself & binding to a custom datasource(DATASET extension) & rendering using report viewer which is working fine. Now I have upgraded the Reporting server to **SSRS 2008 R2**. When executing the same codebase 
 (RDL & Dataset) it is throwing error on report viewer.
 Error: An error has occurred during report processing query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you also upgrade the SQL database to 2008 R2 as well?

If so, try the following to update the report schema:

1. Open the .rdl in Report Builder 3.0. Expand `Data Sources`, select your Data Source, and switch to `Use a connection embedded in my report`
2. `Build` a new connection string to your SQL server and database, and ensure that you use `Windows Authentication`. I'm not sure why, but `SQL Authentication` errors out sporadically.
3. `Test Connection` and press `OK`.
4. For each of your `Datasets`, open them up and `Refresh Fields` and press `OK`.
5. Save the report.

I have experienced this in the past. This will essentially force a schema update of the report. It's a bit of a dirty workaround, but I've found it to be successful. If one of your datasets fails to refresh, you'll receive an error explaining what's wrong with the underlying SQL.

Comment: I am fetching data from oracle database in my code as a dataset and passing that dataset as reportparameter when creating a report. I am able to create datasource successfully on reportServer (as i can see in Report server explorer) but when report viewer start rendering the report it shows the above listed error.

Comment: <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource101</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@DataSource">
            <Value>Parameters!DataSource.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
        <CommandText>DealOrderUnitTable</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
 </DataSets>
<ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="Datasource">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>Datasource</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>

Comment: I am passing dataset as xml string in report parameter.. same mechanism is working in 2005 but not in 2008